# How to transmit the text color from a WinForm to an other in C#

Tags: c#, events, colors

I want to change the text color in my WinForm2 so that it becomes the same color in my WinForm1. I managed to transmit the same text from WF2 to F1 with this function:

```
protected void winForm2_myEventHandler(object sender, WinForm1EventArgs e)
{
   rtf1.AppendText(String.Format(e.Tekst)); //rtf1 is a RichTextBox
}
```

I tried this: `rtf1.ForeColor = WinForm2.DefaultForeColor;` but it doesn't works.

Any body can help me to fix my problem?

Comment: Can't you just store the Color in an object and pass it through the constructor?

Comment: I have to use the Color object of my F2 so i could use it in my F1 then i will get the same text color of F2 in F1.

Comment: I'm still not entirely following, from what you have described you should be able to store the color you are using in WinForm2, and when you initialize rft1 just require a Color object to be passed through and use that to set the "ForeColor".

Comment: I have 2 RichTextBoxes. rtf1 in F1 and rtf2 in F2. when i write a text in F2 i get it in F1 and i am able to change text color in F2, but now i am trying to get the same text color in F1 from F2 (like i managed with text). When i write in green in F2, green have to be the text color in F1 and so one.